# Xcode Won’t Recogize Bundle ID

Tags: c++, xcode, bundle-identifier

I exported a unity project from my pc onto a flash drive. I then put the project on my Mac and loaded it on Xcode. Normally I would put in a random bundle ID with random characters and I would be able to put the game on my iPhone. Now it says it doesn’t recognize the bundle ID. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Download Unity to your Mac. Load flash drive project to Unity then Build and Run in iOS Build. It should put everything to a XCode project from there you can load to device.